# Изменение оформления сайта. Какие варианты?

Tags: php, дизайн, css

CSS:

```
.v1 {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height:100%;
    background-position : top;
    background-repeat : repeat-y;
    background-image: url('../img/gr2.jpg');
}
```

Я создал в папке img еще две папки _pl1 и pl2, и поместил в них файл gr2.jpg, но с другим цветом. Шаблон один, и хотелось, что бы на разных страницах было другое оформление. Я пробовал вставить php в css, но не получилось.
Вместо:

```
background-image: url('../img/gr2.jpg');
```

Написал:

```
background-image: url('../<?php echo $p ?>/gr2.jpg');
```

а в файле страницы задавал переменную

```
$p = 'img/_pl1';
```

Подскажите можно так делать? Если можно, то где ошибка. Если нельзя, то как. Спасибо.

З.Ы. Я кроме основного домена создал домены 3 уровня и в них надо немного изменить оформление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете файл style.php и в нем прописываете свои стили, а где надо ставите код пхп, например

```
.v1 {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height:100%;
    background-position : top;
    background-repeat : repeat-y;
    background-image: url('../img/<?=$bg; ?>');
}
```

Comment: Т.е. я могу просто переименовать style.css в style.php и вместо 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/style.css" tppabs="http://www.site.com/lib/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
 
спользовать 

    include './lib/css/style.php'; 

Спасибо. А есть другие варианты?

Comment: >спользовать include './lib/css/style.php'; 

именно.
>А есть другие варианты?
а какие еще нужны?)

Comment: Я PHP только начинаю изучать и мне не все еще понятно. Возможно можно как-то по другому менять оформление. Этот вариант я сделал исходя из моих слабых знаний, но возможно профессионалы как-то по другому это делают. 
У меня есть файл шаблона, который неизменен на всех страницах, нужно поменять только некоторые параметры в оформлении. Плодить кучу одинаковых файлов не хотелось бы.

Comment: можно еще по id выгребать нужный файл со стилем, например style.php?id=1

Понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: в вашем случае лучше было бы прописывать стиль, который должен меняться непосредственно в файле шаблона, в зависимости от того, какая страница открыта, опять же по параметру get (например) определяя где сейчас юзер, и исходя из этого в стиле писать то, что нужно
><style>
.some {color: <?=$color; ?>;}
</style>

Comment: А и кстати, скорее не
>include './lib/css/style.php'; 

а 
><link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/style.php?id=1" tppabs="http://www.site.com/lib/css/style.php?id=1" type="text/css" />

Comment: А вот это очень хороший вариант.
Лучше, чем был...)))

Answer (score 1):

просто нужно добавить возможность обрабатывать css, как пхп.
Для чего создать файл .htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .css
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы создали  "папке img еще две папки _pl1 и pl2, и поместил в них файл gr2.jpg" то в стилях они должны быть прописаны.

Не "background-image: url('../img/gr2.jpg');", 
а "background-image: url('../img/**pl1**/gr2.jpg');" или "background-image: url('../img/**pl2**/gr2.jpg');"

Папки нигде не фигурируют в пути к файлу.

Comment: Тогда надо создать столько файлов *.css сколько страниц будет